meta marketing api v20.0 - blame field specs for optimization goal
There seems to be a bug in the facebook marketing api v20.0
When you try to create AdSet with IMPRESSION as an optimization goal for the campaign objective as OUTCOME_TRAFFIC, the api always returns
{
"error": {
"message": "Invalid parameter",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"error_data": "{"blame_field_specs":[["optimization_goal"]]}",
"error_subcode": 2490408,
"is_transient": false,
"error_user_title": "Performance goal isn't available",
"error_user_msg": "You can't use the selected performance goal with your campaign objective. Please select a different goal or edit your campaign.",
"fbtrace_id": "AemKqGCO7_RymPyjuXcJJYp"
}
}
I tried from both facebook business sdk of v20.0 and using graph url v20.0
https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/act_12xxxxxxxx/adsets?access_token=EAAwpjCkZBW7YBO4CSJex2ek2whxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
There is no problem with v19.0 and v18.0
Has anyone came across this problem?
